# Reading arduino serial connection in python

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to connect to my Ardiuno with Python on my Ubuntu computer. I tried this example:
http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python

But I always get:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 282, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 289, in open
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/tty.usbserial'
>>>
```

I can use the serial connection in sketch without any problems. I also added my user to the groups tty and dialout.

How do I connect to my Arduino using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list the serial ports first. I'm not sure dev/tty.usbserial is correct.

You try do `ls /dev/tty*` in Terminal, pehaps your Arduino board will pop up as `ttyACM0` or something like that(sorry, haven't used Ubuntu in a while).

You can also check out the [PySerial finding ports article](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html)(may need PySerial 2.7 or newer)